# How to make a div fade out instead disappearing using code like this? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, for-loop

I made a `div` and a `button`. Made a function that changes the opacity of the `div` in JavaScript.
Then I made an `array` of opacities and a `for` loop and kept the opacity that I want on each loop. But I don't know what is wrong?
Please don't give me suggestions like I should use jQuery or some other library. I want to do it in JavaScript!(without any library)
Here see my code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" href="http://s3images.coroflot.com/user_files/individual_files/original_240004_eFk2sUc1K3KyXWz60vHrALo5H.jpg">
    <title>JavaScript</title>
    <style>
        body
        {
            font-family:ebrima;
            color:black;
        }
        #box
        {
            height:100px;
            width:100px;
            background:red;
            opacity:1;
        }
    </style>
</head>


<body id="mainBody">

    <div id="box"></div>


    <button type="button" id="b" onClick="lessTheOppacity()">OPACITY</button>


    <script>
    function lessTheOppacity()
    {
        var box = document.getElementById("box");
        var oppArray = ["0.9", "0.8", "0.7", "0.6", "0.5", "0.4", "0.3", "0.2", "0.1", "0"];

        for (var x = 0; x < 10;x++)
        {
            box.style.opacity=oppArray[x];
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't complicate it, you can do this with CSS3 transitions very easily. And for browser that don't support it then fallback to `visibility: hidden`

Comment: @elclanrs It's not "complicating" it. What if the OP wants to fade an element for _all_ browsers? There's nothing wrong with that. Besides that, the OP also said "don't give me suggestions [...] I want to do this with Javascript!" Pretty sure you just read over that part.

Comment: Oh? and don't you know it makes all your website slow and sometimes it just don't execute. CSS is really not good man!

Comment: Why are you using an array of opacity values to fade? Just subtract `0.1` each iteration and stop when you reach `<= 0`. (And use `setTimeout()` as shown in the answer below.) Or for smoother animation subtract `0.05` at a time...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function lessTheOppacity()
{
    var box = document.getElementById("box");
    var oppArray = ["0.9", "0.8", "0.7", "0.6", "0.5", "0.4", "0.3", "0.2", "0.1", "0"];
    var x = 0;
    (function next() {
        box.style.opacity = oppArray[x];
        if(++x < oppArray.length) {
            setTimeout(next, 100); //depending on how fast you want to fade
        }
    })();
}
```

**Explanation:**

(1) `next` is a function that will advance us to the next opacity. I chose its name arbitrarily.

```
(function next() {
    ...
})();
```

defines the function and then calls it immediately.

(2) `++x` means "increase the value of `x` by one and give me that value". We use it to increment `x` and to check whether we need to continue fading the element.

(3) We want the fade to happen gradually, over time. Yours happens all at once, so the user only sees the last one, `"0.0"`.

Here, the `setTimeout` waits 100 milliseconds before calling the `next` function and going to the next opacity.

See [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) documentation for more info.

**Futher notes:**

A more flexible approach would be to allow the fade time to vary, and to calculate the steps accordingly, not always having ten, or to have a non-linear fade. But that is more complicated, and it is why people usually use jQuery.

```
// this does a linear fade
function fade(element, duration) {
    var start = new Date;
    (function next() {
        var time = new Date - start;
        if(time < duration) {
            box.style.opacity = 1 - time / duration;
            requestAnimationFrame(next);
        } else {
            box.style.opacity = '0';
        }
    })();
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/badU7/)

Also, if you can depend on the browser supporting CSS3 transitions, I would look into doing it that way. It is cleaner and generally preferred.

Comment: Hey I am a begginner! Can you tell me what `++x` and `setTimeout` and `next`  means?

Comment: _"A more flexible approach would be to allow the fade time to vary,...But that is more complicated"_ - It's easy enough to dump the array and allow the fade time to be specified as a function parameter: http://jsfiddle.net/UwH84/2/

Comment: Hey why do we use parentheses before and after `function next()`?

Comment: Faiz, see (1). It is basically shorthand for `function next() {} next();`@nnnnnn, even better would be to use `requestAnimationFrame` to decide the steps at which to fade.

Answer (score 0):

Don't iterate through an array of values that you can easily calculate. This should show you how it works:

```
var opacity = 1;
function lto() {
    var box = document.getElementById('box');
    opacity -= 0.1;
    if (opacity < 0)
        {opacity = 1; return;}
    box.style.opacity = opacity;
    setTimeout(lto, 100);
}
```

In your case, you run from full opacity to transparent without the browser getting even a chance to draw it anew. So instead of the function above, use some asynchronous event ( `setTimeout(…)`) to actually call the `lto` function

Comment: typo, comma instead of semicolon …

Answer (score 0):

You can't. But you can use jQuery instead JavaScript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/jpg" href="http://s3images.coroflot.com/user_files/individual_files/original_240004_eFk2sUc1K3KyXWz60vHrALo5H.jpg">
    <title>JavaScript</title>
    <style>
        body
        {
            font-family:ebrima;
            color:black;
        }
        #box
        {
            height:100px;
            width:100px;
            background:red;
            opacity:1;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
</head>


<body id="mainBody">

    <div id="box"></div>


    <input type="button" class="opacity" value="opacity" />


    <script>
         $(".opacity").click(function () {
             $('#box').toggle("slow");
         });  
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It's more easy. You can use **toggle()**, **slideToggle()** or **fadeToggle()** functions for animations.

Comment: _"You can't."_ - Of course you can. _"But you can use jQuery instead JavaScript"_ - jQuery can't do anything that can't be done with plain JavaScript, given that jQuery is "just" a collection of functions written in JavaScript. So yes, jQuery makes it easier, but it's not at all necessary.

Comment: OK dude. I was just trying to help you.